# youtube apis v3 return playlist

Tags: java, youtube-api, google-api, youtube-data-api

how can I get the number of playlists in a youtube channel and in each playlist details about number of videos that it contains

the playlistitems.list returns all the uploaded videos. I need them sorted in there lists to use them in my app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [playlists#list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/list) method with a `channelId` parameter to get the playlists and, for each playlist, call [playlistItems#list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list) with the `playlistId` parameter.